# Can std::vector capacity/size/reserve be used to manually manage vector memory allocation?

Tags: c++, vector, standard-library, c++98

I'm running very time sensitive code and would need a scheme to reserve more space for my vectors at a specific place in the code, where I can know (approximately) how many elements will be added, instead of having std do it for me when the vector is full.

I haven't found a way to test this to make sure there are no corner cases of std that I do not know of, therefore I'm wondering how the capacity of a vector affects the reallocation of memory. More specifically, would the code below make sure that automatic reallocation **never** occurs?

**code**

```
std::vector<unsigned int> data;
while (condition) {
    // Reallocate here
    // get_elements_required() gives an estimate that is guaranteed to be >= the actual nmber of elements.
    unsigned int estimated_elements_required = get_elements_required(...);
    if ((data.capacity() - data.size()) <= estimated_elements_required) {
        data.reserve(min(data.capacity() * 2, data.max_length - 1));
    }

    ...

    // NEVER reallocate here, I would rather see the program crash actually...
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < get_elements_to_add(data); ++i) {
        data.push_back(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

`estimated_elements_required` in the code above is an estimate that is guaranteed to be equal to, or greater than, the actual number of elements that will be added. The code actually adding elements performs operations based on the capacity of the vector itself, changing the capacity halfway through will generate incorrect results.

Comment: You probably want to use `resize(()` instead of `reserve()`.

Comment: And you're not just invoking `data.reserve(elements_required);` because.... ? Or did you mean `elements_required` to actually be `elements_to_add` (the source of which is a mystery in this code)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He increases the size below when he adds the elements.

Comment: Yes, you can use `reserve` carefully so that you control exactly when memory is allocated. It is guaranteed to not be allocated unless you add beyond the current `capacity`.

Comment: how is `elements_to_add` related to `elements_required`, `data.size()` and `data.capacity()*2` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work.

From the definition of `reserve`:

> It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`.

Comment: It's the iff part I'm worried about. The possibility for some heuristics that assumes bulk adds and reallocated when size > 90% of capacity or something like that.

Comment: @user3235200: That would be illegal, because they'd be breaking the user's pointer/reference invalidation semantics.

Comment: @DeadMG: An alternative interpretation would be that you have to check `capacity()` after every `push_back` call and if it is unchanged then you know that no reallocation happened.

Comment: I'd presume that `if` in this quote means `if and only if`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I meant `if and only if` when I wrote **`iff`**, but not when I wrote *`if`*, just to clarify.

Comment: I was referring to Mankarse's post

Comment: In general, the standard does distinguish between "if" and "if and only if". However, for `std::vector::reserve()`, the standard guarantees, that `... no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to reserve() until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of capacity()`